# Why has bitrate changed after remuxing with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, codec, bitrate

I am running this command to remux a .VOB file into a .mov file, without re-encoding.

`ffmpeg -i input.VOB -c copy output.mov`

The details of the movies' codec, framerate and bitrate in QuickTime's movie inspector are:

input.VOB:

```
Format: MPEG-2 Video, 720 x 576 (786 x 576)
AC3, 48000 Hz, Stereo (L R)
FPS: 25
Data Rate: 9.46 Mbit/s
```

output.mov:

```
Format: 'm2v1', 720 x 576 (768 x 576)
AC3, 48000 Hz, Stereo (L R)
FPS: 25
Data Rate: 4.82 Mbit/s
```

Why is the bitrate in output.mov half the size, when the codecs and frame rate haven't changed?

Has there been any loss of quality in this conversion?

Comment: It looks like a quirk in QT. The file sizes should be nearly the same.

Comment: Yes the file size of the .VOB is 1.4GB and the file size of the .mov is 1.37GB

Comment: I just used `ffprobe` to look at the bitrates. It is showing "bit_rate": "4929452" for the .VOB and "bit_rate": "4826042" for the .mov, so that supports that it is just a QT quirk